# Android Studio Importing project

Tags: android, android-studio

So I am trying to migrate my companies android projects over to use Android Studio from Eclipse. We have SVN as our repository. I checkout a project from the SVN site and store it on my local C drive. I then imported the project into Android Studio where it copied this directory into its own environment. So when I make changes to this project in Android Studio. How do I sync with the local directory to both pull in and push changes made. Then sync with the SVN repo. Yes I found that Android studio has a version control system but I've already made some changes and want to push these changes to my local repo and then commit when ready. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to work in Android Studio's "workspace" directory. My suggestion:

1. Move your converted Android Studio project from the Android
   Studio projects folder (e.g. `D:\AndroidStudioProjects\`) to your
   local SVN repository (e.g. `C:\SVN\`). Then that code is version controlled by whatever software You use for SVN.
2. Start Android Studio, click `Open Project`, and simply open your project from the version controlled location. Also Android Studio will likely detect that the project is in a repository (at least in case of GIT, it is so), and basic functionality (Push, Pull, etc) will be available.